# Collapsing and Expanding lists in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a tutorial to make collapsible lists in HTML.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="test('node1')">hello</a>
    <ul id="node3" style="display:none">
        <li>Sub-item 1</li>
        <li>Sub-item 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="test('node2')">test</a>
    <ul id="node3" style="display:none">
        <li>Sub-item 1</li>
        <li>Sub-item 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

node 3,4,5,etc

I'm trying to collapse all these tables using the following JavaScript:

```
function test2(id, link) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == '') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        link.innerHTML = 'Expand';
    } else {
        e.style.display = '';
        link.innerHTML = 'Collapse';
    }
}
```

But when I call the function I'm not too sure what to enter to select all nodes. I still need the individual control on each node, so I can't change all the names to be the same.

```
<a href="#" onclick="test2('node????', this)">Collapse</a>
```

Comment: @jlordo no reason to tell everybody your edit reason...

Comment: I don't think that this can be done without using jQuery. Are you OK with that [jQuery]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the class attribute for that.

```
<li>
 <a href="#" onclick="test('node1')">hello</a>
 <ul id="node1" class="node" style="display:none">
  <li>Sub-item 1</li>
  <li>Sub-item 2</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>
 <a href="#" onclick="test('node2')">test</a>
 <ul id="node2" class="node" style="display:none">
  <li>Sub-item 1</li>
  <li>Sub-item 2</li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Assuming that you really want to collapse all of them and not toggle their visibility you could write something like this...

```
function test2(className, link) {
 var e = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

 for (var i = 0, len = e.length; i < len; i++) {
  e[i].style.display = "none";
 }

 link.innerHTML = "Expand";
}
```

...and call it like that...

```
<a href="#" onclick="test2('node', this)">Collapse</a>
```

Keep in mind that getElementsByClassName does not work in older browsers (< IE9).

**UPDATE:**
An alternative way of achieving this is by using CSS and changing the class-name of a mutual parent element. Here's a sample CSS code for that:

```
#mutualParent.hide-nodes li.node {
 display: none;
}
```

Then change your function like this...

```
function test2(className) {
 document.getElementById("mutualParent").className += className;
}
```

...and call it like that:

```
<a href="#" onclick="test2('hide-nodes')">Collapse</a>
```

If you want to toggle the visibility using the test()-function you need to remove the className first or otherwise it stays hidden. Also for this code to work you need to remove the style-attribute from the `<ul>` tags because style attributes have a higher priority.

Comment: could you please give an example of the css method? ahving trouble implementing it, thanks